# Calling a method that doesn't access data on a null object pointer sometimes works, sometimes crashes. Why doesn't it always crash?

Tags: c++

Let's say we have this class:

```
class MagicalMysteryClass {

public:
   doSomethingWithoutTouchingInstanceData() {
        usleep(1000);
   }
private:
   int someData;
}
```

And we try to call that method via a null pointer:

```
MagicalMysteryClass *obj = 0;
obj->doSomethingWithoutTouchingInstanceData();
```

On one machine of mine, this errant call actually works about 90% the time.  On another machine, it crashes about 90% of the time.

Why does this work at all?

If I cannot reliably expect a call to a null pointer to behave in a consistent manner, how can I projected myself against this?

Comment: UB, anything can happen.

Comment: You may need to dig into the assembler output to figure this out. The short example you've shown should be consistent at least, even if it is technically undefined.

Comment: "If I cannot reliably expect a call to a null pointer to crash, how can I projected myself against this?" Just try to avoid writing code that has undefined behavior in the first place. Tools like valgrind will find some of these problems for you.

Comment: Why so downvoted?  Is this a dumb question?  For someone new to C++ coming from another language/runtime where null pointer behavior is very well defined, this behavior is surprising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to protect yourself against accidental usage of a null pointer, you can create your own smart pointer class that throws an error if you try to dereference it.

```
template<typename T>
class ProtectedPtr
{
public:
    ProtectedPtr(T* p = nullptr) : ptr(p)
    {
    }
    T& operator*()
    {
        if (ptr == nullptr)
            throw std::runtime_error("Attempt to dereference null pointer");
        return *ptr;
    }
    T* operator->()
    {
        if (ptr == nullptr)
            throw std::runtime_error("Attempt to dereference null pointer");
        return ptr;
    }
private:
    T* ptr;
};
```